# How to sort content of nodes by dynamic fields?

Tags: nodes

I have a content type named "**Article**". "**Article**" has fields: **Body**, **Image**, **Tags**, etc. I want to create a **sort handler** that will sort *node content* by content type fields. I know, every field has its own table in database. So, If I choose "**body**" field, it's database table will be `field_body` and has column `body_value`. How to sort content on basis of field's column, specially when we don't know which field our user is going to choose next.

I mean fields are dynamic and so the sorting should also be dynamic. For some static non-fields like "**title**", "**node id**", "**node_created**", etc, I used below approach to reach the scenario.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery(); //get all nodes of content type selected by each block
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', $content_type)
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
foreach ($sort_fields_array[0] as $sfaa_key => $sfaa_value) {
    if(!empty($sfaa_key) && $sfaa_value == 'Assc'){
    $query->propertyOrderBy($sfaa_key, 'ASC');
    }
     elseif(!empty($sfaa_key) && $sfaa_value == 'Desc'){
    $query->propertyOrderBy($sfaa_key, 'DESC');
    }
}
$results = $query->execute();
```

`$sfa`a has all dynamic fields and non-fields. **This code is working for non-fields** like title, nid, etc. **but not for dynamic fields** like body, image etc.

if `$sfaa == title`, then sorting will be done by **title** else if it is `= nid` then sorting will proceed by **node id**.

And if `$sfaa == body`, it gives me **fatal error** `node.body` doesn't exist.

**How to overcome this error or sort content by dynamic fields?**

**Edit 1:**

I got some half way clue that's why editing here.
If I use `->fieldOrderBy('field_photo', 'fid', 'DESC')` , no doubt it will sort content by fields. But can we make it's column **(fid)** here dynamic?

**Edit 2:**
I am using [db_field_exists($table, $field)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_field_exists/7) to check if field exists or not. But, Isn't there any other way to get columns of the field dynamically for sorting. I don't think, it is impossible, as **Views module** is using some kind of similar approach in **Views Sort Criteria**

*Modified code is shown below:*

```
 if(db_field_exists('node',$sfaa_key) && $sfaa_value == 'Assc'){
      //  print "if condition executed";
    $query->propertyOrderBy($sfaa_key, 'ASC');
    }
     elseif(!(db_field_exists('node',$sfaa_key)) && $sfaa_value == 'Desc'){
       //  print "else condition executed";
    //$query->propertyOrderBy($sfaa_key, 'DESC');
      $query->fieldOrderBy($sfaa_key, 'value', 'ASC');
```

Comment: Wonder why you need that, you can use views. But still you if you want to sort from fields then you need to add a join with your query.

Comment: You are using propertyOrderBy. This does not work for non properties. Properties are actually fields from the entity base table - node in this case. To order by field values use fieldOrderBy.

Comment: using a views is better option.

Comment: Is there any function distinguish fields and non-fields so taht I can check the property, if it is field use fieldOrderBy else use propertyOrderBy?

Comment: If I use ->fieldOrderBy('field_photo', 'fid', 'DESC') , no doubt it will sort content by fields. But can we make it's column (fid) here dynamic?

Comment: Use field_info_field to check if the field exists. If yes you could derive the index from the field type that is returned by the function. For example if the field type is list_integer the index is value, for type entityreference it's target_id. Unfortunately that is manual work..

Comment: I am using [db_field_exists($table, $field)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_field_exists/7) to check if field exists or not. But, Isn't there any other way to get columns of the field dynamically for sorting. I don't think, it is impossible, as Views module is using some kind of similar approach